# Why implement the inherited abstract method?

Tags: java, android, class, abstract

I have some confusion in the "beginning android game" book, chapter 3, pg.100-101. I think I've follow the book instruction, however the IDE still give me this error:

> The type MyAwesomeGame must implement the inherited abstract method Game.getFileIO()

how can I fix it, or is it something about implement that I don't grasp it yet?

and here are the codes:

```
public class MyAwesomeGame extends AndroidGame {
    public Screen getStartScreen(){
        return new MySuperAwesomeStartScreen(this);
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class AndroidGame implements Game {

}
```

```
public interface Game {
    public Input getInput();

    public FileIO getFileIO();

    public Graphics getGraphics();

    public Audio getAudio();

    public void setScreen(Screen screen);

    public Screen getCurrentScreen();

    public Screen getStartScreen();
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be the only error.. you have to implements all functions you declared in **Game** in your **MyAwesomeGame** class.

Comment: There is something about implementation you don't quite seem to grasp. What do you think it means? (I'm not asking to be me mean, but to try and understand the confusion.)

Comment: i mean the theory and concept of implementation. in this case, the reason why the error pop up even though i followed the book's code.

Comment: "*When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass **usually** provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, the subclass must also be declared abstract.*" Have a look at this site for more information on Java Abstract Classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: If this is the book's code, the book provided incomplete code. If the book said the code is complete, the book is wrong. Given a book and javac, if they disagree, you can almost always assume javac is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concrete class must implement all the abstract methods of its ancestor abstract classes.

In your case the abstract parent class - `AndroidGame` - implements an interface - `Game`, so each concrete sub-class of that abstract class (such as your `MyAwesomeGame` class) must implement all the methods of that interface.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, however the code shown above are exactly the same as shown in the book "beginning android game".. which are suppose to work as it were. implement the adstract methods do clear the red underscore error, but it won't work on the emulator/device..

Comment: @user2779114 I'm sorry, but I don't have that book. All I have is the code the you posted, and my answer states what wrong with it. As for why doesn't it work after you fixed the errors, that a different question, and I can't answer it without knowing more about your code and the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to create a class implementing an interface you must implement all the methods in your class since all the methods in an interface are implicitely abstract.

In your case you haven't implemented any method of Game interface in your concrete sub class or abstract class. That is the reason for the issue.